# preg_match to find json data from html

Tags: php

text html

```
,["pid","VJHggI_XrKLWQ"]
,["image_full","1080|https://pic.website.com/bdnsns,800|https://pic2.website.com/bdnsns"]
```

how can I get string `https://pic.website.com/bdnsns`

I tried this code:

```
$str = file_get_contents($str);

if(preg_match('/"image_full","1080|(.*?)"/', $str, $m)){
  echo  $m[1] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you properly parse JSON data, if the input comes in correct JSON format?

Comment: no json data source, it just html from file_get_content

Comment: If it is proper HTML, why not parse it?

Comment: how? i use json_decode($str,true) but blank

Comment: `json_decode` can only be used for **valid** JSON structures. If your source data is in HTML format, something like `DOMDocument` will help. But the given example does not look like valid JSON or HTML...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,I hope its helpfull to you.If url is in between two delimeters then this solution are work perfectly.

```
$str = file_get_contents("test.html");
print_r(extract_unit($str,'|',','));
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
 {
  $pos = stripos($string, $start);

  $str = substr($string, $pos);

  $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));

  $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);

  $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);

  $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces

  return $unit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, parsing this kind of output is not the right thing to do. You need to get the data properly in JSON format. If you need it anyway, then here is what you could do.

```
<?php

$str = ',["pid","VJHggI_XrKLWQ"],["image_full","1080|https://pic.website.com/bdnsns,800|http://pic2.website.com/bdnsns"],["image_full","1080|https://pic.website.com/bdnsns,800|https://pic2.website.com/bdnsns"]';

$m = array();

if(preg_match_all('/\d+\|http(s)?:\/\/.+(\,|\")/U', $str, $m)){
    foreach($m[0] as $each_match){
        $each_match = trim(trim($each_match,","),'"');
        $new_matches = array(); 
        if(preg_match('/http(s)?:\/\/.+/',$each_match,$new_matches)){
            echo $new_matches[0],"\n";
        }
    }
}
```